# blockquote does not return anything

Tags: html, imgur

This [sample](https://codepen.io/harrygreen/pen/bNXGYo) works in codepen, but not work in my html file?
why is this happening?

i already tried to add https:// to href, but still not working

```html
<script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
a
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="KUteCdn">
  <a href="//imgur.com/KUteCdn">View post on imgur.com</a>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: Are you getting errors in the console on your site?

Comment: no message appears, is it a CORS problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that this is a CORS related issue, verify this by checking your js console. To rectify this, you can run a simple HTTP server and serve the html file from there.

on Mac OS you run the following in terminal from your working directory

`http-server -p 4090 .`

In your web browser, navigate to `http://localhost:4090`

This will stop you from receiving such an erroe

Comment: Thanks! I used the vs code liveserver to run the page and it worked,I'm just practicing so I had not used the live server before

Comment: Glad you got it working, no worries at all, if you need anymore help hit me on Instagram, I check there more often @anthonycarnell